# Game crashes when starting

Tags: dark-souls-2

I'm having trouble beginning a game of Dark Souls 2 (Scholar of the 1st Sin) on my PS3. The game starts and loads fine, and I even get the beginning cut scene, but when the actual game comes to start, it shuts down. This even shuts off my PS3. All other games work just fine.

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Have you checked the quality of the disc? Or tried a reinstall?